# How to get the key of a Firebase Object

Tags: arrays, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the Key of a Firebase object without using snapshot?

I have done the research below.

Using the code:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://johnsoncompany.firebaseio.com/people')

var firstPerson = ref.orderByChild("first").limitToFirst(1);

var key = $firebaseObject(firstPerson);
```

..I get the object below:

```
{  
   "5":{  
      "first":"Jennifer",
      "last":"Robert",
      "mobile":"121 364 135",
   }
}
```

Firebase had given my object the key "5" since the data is contained in an array of values. This was the 6th value.

The challenge is that in-order to get the value "Jennifer", I have to know that the key is "5".

I will then use the code:

```
var firstPerson = $firebaseObject(ref.child('5'))

var firstName = firstPerson.first; //Returns Jennifer
```

I know I can use the code below to get the key '5':

```
    ref.orderByChild("first").limitToFirst(1).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        alert(snapshot.key());
    });
```

The challenge is that there is a delay before it returns the key. This results to an malfuctioning app.

Is there a way I can get the key without snapshot

```
ref.orderByChild("first").limitToFirst(1).key(); //This doesn't work
```

Comment: There is no way to read the key from Firebase (or likely any cloud based database) without asynchronously loading that data.  But it all depends on why you want to retrieve that specific object. If it's not on the knowledge that it's item 5, then is it based on another property. For example if you want to get the user based on their number you'd `ref.orderByChild('mobile').equalTo('121 364 135').on(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around it, you could see if it helps

```
ArticlesRef.orderByChild('title')
        .equalTo('one2three')
         .once('value')
         .then(function(snapshot){
            let value = snapshot.val()
            if(value){
            let key = Object.keys(value)[0];
            //since the value is an object you can get the key given by firebase
            //you can add more code});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you might have found a solution to your issue by now, but here is what I use to retrieve the key of an object. I then use that same key to run another query (filter).

```
itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
  var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    items.push({
      active: child.val().active,
      profile: child.val().profile,
      image: child.val().image,
      description: child.val().description,
      title: child.val().title,
      _key:child.key, //<--------------this is where I get the key
    });
  });
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items),
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the spread operator to assign:

```
itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
  var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    items.push({
      _key: child.key,
      ...child.val()
    });
  });

});
```

makes it easier when adding new properties to your data, without maintaining your code.